# how to export brushes(java, sql, c) to a pdf file while using syntaxHighlighter

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, syntaxhighlighter

I want to export html data to pdf file. I also need to export some `java code` to pdf file and that java code should be displayed with syntaxhighlighter classes but it is not.

e.g.

```
this text is to be export to pdf

Public Static Void Main()
{
   Console.Writeline("hello");
}
```

I am using this line of code.

```
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
        cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes/codeviewer/styles/shCore.css"), true);
        cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes/codeviewer/styles/shThemeDefault.css"), true);

        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, pdfWriter)));
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser Parser = new XMLParser(true, worker);
        Parser.Parse(reader);
```

but css classes are not being applied to the `java code` which are being loaded from some js file. please help. thanks in advance.